# What happens to python time.sleep when I close my laptop?

Tags: python, time, sleep

If I run

```
time.sleep(600)  # 10 minutes
```

and close my laptop for 5 minutes and open it again, will it sleep for another 10 minutes or 5 minutes? Will the code just pause, or will it read the time and recognize that 5 minutes passed?

Comment: The quickest way is probably to try it and see :) this may depend on which OS you are running on as well.

Comment: Looking at [the code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/23a567c11ca36eedde0e119443c85cc16075deaf/Modules/timemodule.c#L2071) it's going to be Windows against the rest of the world once again.

Comment: @KlausD. - It's even less clear than that. What happens on closing the lid of a laptop varies by OS and can be changed in settings. The only practicable solution for anyone to answer this question for their own setup is to try it themselves (and do so again whenever they change anything that might affect it).

Comment: The approach of testing something locally usually leads to excuses like "Works on my machine!". A more theoretical answer would be more helpful to the author of the question, I guess.

Answer (score -1):

Tested with 60 seconds, and the code pauses, at least on windows 10.

Comment: This only tells us what happens on that specific machine, and then only until you change the settings regarding what happens when you close the lid.

Answer (score -1):

the code stops when you close your laptop as your laptop goes into sleep mode. That's why `time.sleep` code gets stopped along with the other code.